# Proving $|\exp(z)-1| \leq |z| \exp|z|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

Tried proving the exercise in "A Pathway to complex Analysis - S Kumaresan"

it is to prove $|\exp(z)-1| \leq |z|\exp|z|$

I started with $\exp(z)=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+...$
$$\implies \exp(z)-1=z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+...$$
$$\implies |\exp(z)-1|=\left|z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+...\right|$$
$$\implies |\exp(z)-1|=\left|z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+...\right| \leq |z|+\frac{|z|^2}{2!}+\frac{|z|^3}{3!}+...$$
$$\implies  |z|+\frac{|z|^2}{2!}+\frac{|z|^3}{3!}+...=|z|(1+\frac{|z|}{2!}+\frac{|z|^2}{3!}+...) $$ $$\leq |z|(1+|z|+\frac{|z|^2}{2!}+...) = |z|\exp(|z|)$$

Is this proof correct? Or are there any subtle mistakes?
I listed the things which I used in proving this

- $ |\sum_n(z_n)|\leq \sum_n|z_n|$
- Scalar multiple of a series converges to the scalar multiple of its sum.

Kindly verify and tell if there is any mistake in the proof... TIA

Comment: This all looks good!

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%7Ce%5Ez-1%7C%5Cleq%7Cz%7Ce%5E%7B%7Cz%7C%7D%24&p=1), there's the fairly closely related [How can I prove these complex inequalities?](/q/2504820) and [Proving a complex inequality in polar form](/q/1767191).

Comment: Alternatively, you can use ${\rm e}^z  - 1 = z\int_0^1 {{\rm e}^{zt} {\rm d}t} $.

Comment: Small nit:  The second to last line should not start with the arrow $\Longrightarrow$, as it's a true statement on its own and not being implied by the previous line.